# tensorflow tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I'm trying to play with "tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell" with TF on python.

Reading here "https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicLSTMCell", in the "**init**" method, I see the param "num_units"
with description "int, The number of units in the LSTM cell."

But ... wait a moment "number of UNITS"? Which type of units? The class is called "...LSTMCell" but from "num_units" it seem that we are speaking about a layer, not a single neuron.

I'm confused. Any help is appreciated.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Its like nodes in the hidden layers of a feed forward network